# Evaluating accuracy of the classifier based on sample?

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, sampling, accuracy, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a rather odd question which unfortunately goes beyond my knowledge of stats so any advice will be much appreciated. We built a clustering model on the text data (LDA) and then assigned classes based on the membership in specific cluster (just eyeballed top documents and top words in each cluster).

Let's say I have 11 clusters overall and 18000 documents. We then randomly picked up 100 documents from the dataset and then manually checked which classes were assigned based on clustering and determined via judgement which classes it actually should have been assigned purely from business standpoint. Turned out that out of 100 randomly picked documents 25 were wrong.

Now, obviously we can just say 'our approach is right 75% of the time' but it will be too naive - we are just using a small sample and we are not accounting for number of classes or how frequent certain classes are. Is there a good way to correct our judgement about accuracy of algorithm based on understanding the sample size and taking into account number of clusters?

Thank you!

Comment: "Turned out that out of 100 randomly picked documents 25 were wrong." -- How did you determine they were wrong? Was the topic model not able to find the correct clusters? Have you considered utilizing the perplexity measure? The perplexity measure tries to determine how good of a fit the topic model is on some test data.

Comment: @kedarps the conclusion was drawn based on manual verification by business users. They literally read the documents and concluded that the classification was wrong. Our task is not to just minimize perplexity (which we did) but to take business requirements into account - hence we use Guided LDA. For each topic proper terms are used to define them but there are some cases when topic assignment will still be wrong. In any case our task is not to improve the model but to make a judgement about accuracy on whole population.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.